# Does empty list have a length?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am writing a function that takes two arrays a and b of length n storint int values, and returns the dot product of a and b. That is, it returns an array c of length n such that c[i]=a[i]*b[i],for i=0,...,n-1.

Here is my code.

```
def product(a,b):
    c=[None]*len(a)
    for i in range(len(a)):
        c[i]=a[i]*b[i]
    return c

a=[1,2,3]
b=[2,4,5]
print(product(a,b))

[2, 8, 15]
```

When I changed the code `c=[None]*len(a)` to `c=[]`,there would be an error occur, which is `IndexError: list assignment index out of range`.

I can't understand why the list c must include `*len(a)`?
Because the output of `len([]*len("abc"))` is `0`.
And I also can't udnerstand the difference between `[]` and `[None]`. Can anyone help me?

Comment: `c = []`, `c.append(a[i] * b[i])`…?! You can't *set* a value on an index that doesn't exist.

Comment: ``[]`` is a list with no elements, ``[None]`` is a list with a single element – ``None``.

Comment: Also: `return [i * j for i, j in zip(a, b)]` would be a lot simpler and more pythonic.

Comment: `[] * 3 -> Out[1]: []` while `[None] * 3` -> `Out[2]: [None, None, None]`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because a list is not resized by index lookups, you either need to pre-allocate a list size (which is what you did), or append to the list. Since the index you're attempting to write to does not exists in the first place, you get an `Index out of range error`.

```py
def product(a,b):
    c=[]
    for i in range(len(a)):
        c.append(a[i]*b[i])
    return c

a=[1,2,3]
b=[2,4,5]
print(product(a,b))
[2, 8, 15]
```

Or, in much simpler terms.

```py
def product(a,b):
    return [a[i]*b[i] for i in range(len(a))]

a=[1,2,3]
b=[2,4,5]
print(product(a,b))
[2, 8, 15]
```